# Can knockout components be composed recursively?

Tags: knockout.js

Can knockout components be composed recursively - I'm trying to build ui which has panels within panel within panels ....

I know / think I can do it with knockout **templates** but I'm trying to do it with **components** (because these seem like the future (?).

I'm going to try anyway and see if I can make it work. But I'd love to know if I'm wasting my time.

Comment: Don't use components because "they are the future". The main difference between a component and a template is that the template only has the DOM elements (HTML) with bindings to the main viewmodel properties, and a component has its own viewmodel. So, the template is fully coupled to the main view model, while a component is completely independent, and it's only coupled to the main view model through optional parameters. Besides, if you use AMD, you can easyly load your componentes asynchronously.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I hope this sample of recursive components helps you:

```js
function ComponentModel(params) {
  params = params || {};
  params.innerComponentsCount = params.innerComponentsCount || 0;
  var result = {
    name: 'name',
    components: ko.observableArray()
  };
  while(params.innerComponentsCount > 0) {
    var childModel = new ComponentModel();
    childModel.name = childModel.name + params.innerComponentsCount;
    result.components.push(childModel);
    params.innerComponentsCount--;
  }
  return result;
} 

ko.components.register('my-component', {
    template: { element: 'my-component-template' },
    viewModel: {
        createViewModel: function(params, componentInfo) {
            return new ComponentModel(params);
        }
    },
});
 
ko.applyBindings();
```

```css
.my-component {
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding: 5px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.2.0/knockout-min.js"></script>

<template id='my-component-template'>
    <div class="my-component">
      <div data-bind='text: name'></div>
      <!-- ko foreach: components -->
        <my-component></my-component>
      <!-- /ko -->
    </div>
</template>

<my-component params="innerComponentsCount: 2"></my-component>
```

Comment: One of the use cases for templates is that they can be dynamically exchanged. In the case of components, it's also possible to do so by using the `component` binding, and changing the `name` property. That's a very important point.

Comment: @TSV, the `childModel.name = childModel.name + params.innerComponentsCount;` line doesn't seem to be working, when running the code snippet?  The text is just "name" in all instances; no trailing 'count' values...